# Acces to user-created map with Google map API

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible?
With the Google Data api, we could use:
http://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/maps/default/owned
but now that it is deprecated, I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no programatic access to user created data in Google My Maps.

Comment: This is a pitty! Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Can you accept the answer please so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered?